# How to write DataFrames to excel in a loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm having a hard time figuring out why pandas doesn't write anything after running my code.  I assume it's probably a small error I'm not seeing, as I'm still unfamiliar with this sort of thing.

```
import xlsxwriter as xl
import pandas as pd 

#Excel sheet I'm writing to
Individualreport = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx"

#worksheet info using xl
wb = xl.Workbook("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx")
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
ws.set_page_view
ws.set_paper(1)

# ticker list and pipeline data to pull using pandas
Ticklist = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = Ticklist.values.ravel()

PipelineData = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)

###
row_pipe = 2
col_pipe = 1

for i in stocks:
    t = PipelineData.loc[(PipelineData[0]==i)]
    print(t)
##### Where my problem occurs?
    pipelinewriter = pd.ExcelWriter(Individualreport, engine='xlsxwriter')
    t.to_excel(pipelinewriter, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=row_pipe, startcol=col_pipe)
    row_pipe += 47

pipelinewriter.save()    
wb.close()
```

I am wanting it to take each of the Dataframes "t" that print correctly like below, and put them in the excel "individual report" starting in row_pipe, col_pipe.  Then for each t dataframe in i print 47 rows down from the last i.

```
  0                  1  ...         3               4
1  ADVM     ADVM-022 OPTIC  ...   Phase I  Catalyst Soon?
2  ADVM  ADVM-022 INFINITY  ...  Phase II  Catalyst Soon?

[2 rows x 5 columns]
      0  ...                                                  4
3  AERI  ...                                     Catalyst Soon?
4  AERI  ...  Top-line data released Sep 2020.  Non-inferiro...
5  AERI  ...                                                  d
6  AERI  ...                                                  d
7  AERI  ...                                                  d
8  AERI  ...                                                  d

[6 rows x 5 columns]
      0  1  2  3  4
9  AGTC  a  b  c  d
      0                1  2  3  4
10  ALC  Medical Product  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
11  ALDX  a  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
12  ALIM  a  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
13  ARPO  a  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
14  CLSD  a  b  c  d
      0                1  2  3  4
15  COO  Medical Product  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
16  EYEG  a  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
17  EYEN  a  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
18  EYPT  a  b  c  d
       0                1  2  3  4
19  GKOS  Medical Product  b  c  d
       0  1  2  3  4
20  ISEE  a  b  c  d
```

I am trying to use pandas to do this because I keep getting an error that xl doesn't write dataframes when I try doing so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be mixing a few variations of how to open/close workbooks. I don't have your data but try this code and review these [examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html). When I write I don't open the document or add sheets first, by providing the sheetname it'll be created or use an existing.

```
import xlsxwriter #removed as xl
import pandas as pd 

#Excel sheet I'm writing to
Individualreport = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx"

#commented out this block
#worksheet info using xl 
#wb = xl.Workbook("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx")
#ws = wb.add_worksheet()
#ws.set_page_view
#ws.set_paper(1)

# ticker list and pipeline data to pull using pandas
Ticklist = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = Ticklist.values.ravel()

PipelineData = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)

###
row_pipe = 2
col_pipe = 1

pipelinewriter = pd.ExcelWriter(Individualreport, engine='xlsxwriter') #moved this out of the for loop
for i in stocks:
    t = PipelineData.loc[(PipelineData[0]==i)]
    print(t)
    t.to_excel(pipelinewriter, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=row_pipe, startcol=col_pipe)
    row_pipe += 47

pipelinewriter.save()    
#wb.close() #commented out this line
```

You may have to play around with the position of pipelinewriter.save() and the piplinewriter variable line I moved. They may both have to be in the for loop..